# TextMeshPro in Unity shows a vertical line | in Kannada language instead of the text

Tags: unity-game-engine, fonts, localization, textmeshpro, kannada

I am using TextMeshPro to show Kannada language in Unity and there is a problem with ZWNJ character (Unicode: U+200C). It shows up as a vertical line in the text. Example image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLQ9n.png)

[image: Example wrong Kannada text using TextMeshPro]

I have tested with multiple Unicode and Non-Unicode fonts but I get the same result.

The expected text is: ಕೋರ್ಸ್‌ಗಳಿಗೆ ಪ್ರವೇಶ

The string that is causing the problem seems to be near the character  [image: Kannada character] However I do not know Kannada and have no idea how it is structured. It seems like the ZWNJ character can determine the shape of not only the previous character but a series of characters in a word.

That being said, I can edit the font and remove the ZWNJ character so that it won't show up but it will obviously change the text and I that's not what I intend to do.

I have installed a Unity plugin [(Indian Font Corrector with support for Kannada)](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/indian-fonts-corrector-208727) which fixed a few issues of Kannada text but this one particular issue still persists.

Based on what I know so far: Unity doesn't support GSUB to substitute glyphs in font tables for languages such as Kannada, therefore it cannot replace the right characters. For that to work, either a magic update of TextMeshPro or Unity is required, (which is not the case as of today) or, a special font for Kannada is required (which I would apreciate if you know any).

If you have any experience integrating Kannada language in Unity I would love to know how you managed to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the font atlas is missing that character. I think TMP has an atlas generator based on text, at least we have dynamic generation where the system reads all your texts and finds all characters to add them to the atlas